# Удалить класс из svg jquery?

Tags: jquery

Как при клике на новый регион сбрасывать active c других?

```js
$(function() {
  $('.select_region').on('click', function() {
    this.classList.add("active");
  });
});
```

```css
.select_region:hover .st0, .select_region.active .st0 {
    cursor: pointer;
    fill: #297AFF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pg-region__map">
  <style type="text/css">
    .st0 {
      fill: #43495E;
    }
    
    .st1 {
      fill: #297AFF;
    }
    
    .st2 {
      fill: #363647;
    }
    
    .st3 {
      opacity: 0;
      fill: #297AFF;
    }
    
    .st4 {
      fill: #FFFFFF;
    }
    
    .st5 {
      fill: #565673;
    }
    
    .st6 {
      fill: #636A84;
    }
  </style>
  <svg id="usa" viewBox="0 0 1339 812">
                                                                    <g class="select_region" data-id="1">
                                        <path class="st0" d="M91.84,80.26l3.09,1.2c0.94-0.12,3.45-0.38,5.19,0.07c1.96,0.52,3.79,1.18,4.58,3.55
   c0.4,1.2,0.87,1.4,1.85,1.4c2.04,0,6.83,2.26,6.83,6.63c0,2.89-0.32,8.98-0.44,11.24c1.21,0.58,3.37,1.8,4.37,3.47
   c0.77,1.28,2.71,1.54,5.38,1.54c2.03,0,4.03-0.72,4.56-0.92c0.74-0.55,3.07-2.1,4.97-1.21c0.66,0.31,1.06,0.66,1.37,0.93
   c0.45,0.4,0.77,0.68,2.35,0.86c3.19,0.37,4.89,1.39,7.25,2.82l0.15,0.09c0.66,0.4,1.15,0.76,1.53,1.06
   c0.98,0.74,1.4,1.04,3.72,1.01c1.94-0.03,3.02-0.42,3.89-0.75c0.76-0.28,1.48-0.55,2.37-0.42c1.37,0.2,2.05,1.02,2.5,1.56
   c0.18,0.22,0.33,0.4,0.49,0.51c0.61,0.32,4.27,0.66,5.65,0.51c0.41-0.04,1.1-0.27,1.84-0.51c1.32-0.43,2.97-0.96,4.5-0.96
   c1.09,0,1.84,0.26,2.63,0.54c1.07,0.38,2.41,0.85,5.53,0.96c3.5,0.13,6.41-0.54,8.53-1.03c1.2-0.28,2.07-0.48,2.77-0.48
   c1.87,0,9.47,1.66,12.84,2.7c2.77,0.86,21.72,5.93,27.52,7.48c-0.21-4.05,0-8.93,0.2-11.25c0.16-1.87,1.28-6.88,2.19-10.9
   c0.45-2,0.84-3.73,0.99-4.55c0.15-0.79,0.59-2.78,1.21-5.53c1.33-5.88,3.33-14.76,3.86-18.67c0.18-1.3,0.31-2.32,0.41-3.17
   c0.36-2.87,0.47-3.73,1.27-6.07c1.46-4.29,3.15-9.5,3.41-10.8c0.27-1.38,1.12-4.91,1.57-6.82l0.2-0.86
   c0.13-0.57,0.69-4.06,1.21-7.46c-15.82-3.51-25.8-5.91-27.54-6.35c-7.43-1.91-37.81-9.68-42.02-11.1
   c-4.21-1.42-24.36-6.46-24.36-6.46c-3.57-1.08-11.05-3.77-13.6-3.52s-2.64,2.15-2.49,3.03s2.25,2.35,2.84,4.06s3.08,2.1,2.89,4.45
   c-0.2,2.35-1.86,3.38-2.79,3.86c-0.93,0.49-0.15,4.26,0.05,4.65s1.61-0.1,1.52,0.88c-0.1,0.98-1.47,1.86-1.52,2.01
   s-0.1,5.28-0.1,5.28s1.42,0.49,1.86,0.93c0.44,0.44,0.29,2.74-0.05,2.93c-0.34,0.2-2.35,0.05-2.35,0.05
   c-0.44-3.13-1.22-3.03-1.76-5.09c-0.54-2.05-2.91-1.96-2.91-1.96l0.15-3.5c0,0,2.54-1.54,2.89-1.79c0.34-0.24,0.24-2.84-0.32-2.71
   s-4.24,2.63-4.7,3.02c-0.46,0.39-0.68,3.8-0.68,3.8s-4.6,0.77-5.12-0.15c-0.52-0.91-3.46-3.39-9.52-4.5
   c-10.34-1.89-19.24-13.83-20.28-13.63c-1.04,0.2-0.85,2.09-0.91,4.3c-0.07,2.22-2.8,7.96-2.87,9.52s2.15,2.48,2.15,2.48
   s0.33,8.54,0.33,11.09s-0.85,3.46-1.24,4.57c-0.39,1.11,1.11,1.83,1.24,2.67c0.13,0.85,0.59,4.63,0.65,6.39
   c0.07,1.76,4.17,2.74,4.17,2.74v2.09c0,0-5.02-0.26-5.35,0c-0.33,0.26-1.04,5.35-0.91,5.74c0.13,0.39,4.3,0.85,4.3,1.24
   c0,0.39-2.15,5.87-2.35,6c-0.2,0.13-3.72-0.59-4.04-0.46c-0.33,0.13-0.78,3.65-0.65,4.37C90.85,79.26,91.28,79.73,91.84,80.26z"></path>
<path class="st4" d="M132.22,60.98l2.18,7.9h0.03l2.32-7.9h1.53l2.31,7.9h0.03l2.18-7.9h1.47l-2.91,9.91h-1.44l-2.41-7.97h-0.03
    l-2.41,7.97h-1.44l-2.91-9.91H132.22z"></path>
<path class="st4" d="M149.18,66.78V66.6c0-0.48-0.15-0.84-0.44-1.08c-0.29-0.25-0.69-0.37-1.2-0.37c-0.75,0-1.38,0.26-1.89,0.77
    l-0.7-0.84c0.69-0.66,1.6-0.99,2.72-0.99c0.91,0,1.61,0.24,2.07,0.72c0.47,0.48,0.7,1.11,0.7,1.88v2.9c0,0.58,0.03,1.02,0.1,1.32
    h-1.19c-0.07-0.32-0.11-0.63-0.11-0.95h-0.04c-0.49,0.75-1.24,1.12-2.23,1.12c-0.28,0-0.56-0.04-0.83-0.11
    c-0.27-0.07-0.53-0.19-0.77-0.34s-0.44-0.36-0.59-0.64c-0.15-0.28-0.22-0.6-0.22-0.96c0-0.38,0.09-0.72,0.27-1
    s0.41-0.5,0.69-0.66c0.28-0.15,0.64-0.27,1.07-0.36s0.84-0.15,1.23-0.18C148.21,66.79,148.66,66.78,149.18,66.78z M149.18,67.73
    h-0.32c-1.97,0-2.95,0.42-2.95,1.26c0,0.36,0.13,0.63,0.39,0.79c0.26,0.16,0.58,0.24,0.97,0.24c0.6,0,1.07-0.18,1.41-0.54
    c0.34-0.36,0.51-0.83,0.51-1.41V67.73z"></path>
<path class="st4" d="M157.13,65.17l-0.91,0.77c-0.15-0.24-0.36-0.44-0.64-0.59c-0.28-0.15-0.58-0.23-0.9-0.23
    c-0.34,0-0.63,0.07-0.87,0.22s-0.36,0.36-0.36,0.65c0,0.26,0.12,0.46,0.35,0.6s0.62,0.27,1.16,0.39
    c1.48,0.33,2.23,0.98,2.23,1.96c0,0.73-0.25,1.27-0.76,1.62c-0.51,0.35-1.14,0.52-1.88,0.52c-0.52,0-1.02-0.1-1.5-0.31
    s-0.87-0.5-1.18-0.88l0.94-0.8c0.18,0.27,0.43,0.49,0.75,0.67c0.32,0.17,0.66,0.26,1.02,0.26c0.37,0,0.69-0.08,0.94-0.23
    c0.25-0.15,0.38-0.4,0.38-0.74c0-0.29-0.13-0.51-0.4-0.66s-0.71-0.3-1.34-0.45c-0.26-0.06-0.49-0.14-0.69-0.21
    s-0.4-0.18-0.6-0.31s-0.36-0.31-0.48-0.53c-0.11-0.22-0.17-0.48-0.17-0.78c0-0.67,0.25-1.18,0.74-1.52
    c0.49-0.34,1.08-0.51,1.77-0.51c0.48,0,0.95,0.1,1.39,0.29S156.9,64.83,157.13,65.17z"></path>
<path class="st4" d="M160.19,65.27h0.03c0.16-0.34,0.43-0.62,0.82-0.85c0.39-0.23,0.81-0.34,1.28-0.34
    c0.81,0,1.43,0.25,1.85,0.76s0.63,1.15,0.63,1.95v4.12h-1.32v-3.67c0-1.35-0.5-2.03-1.5-2.03c-0.52,0-0.95,0.2-1.29,0.6
    c-0.34,0.4-0.5,0.93-0.5,1.58v3.51h-1.32V60.31h1.32V65.27z"></path>
<path class="st4" d="M168.58,61.87c0,0.23-0.09,0.43-0.26,0.59c-0.17,0.16-0.38,0.25-0.62,0.25c-0.24,0-0.45-0.08-0.62-0.25
    c-0.17-0.16-0.25-0.36-0.25-0.59s0.08-0.43,0.25-0.6s0.37-0.25,0.62-0.25c0.24,0,0.45,0.08,0.62,0.24
    C168.49,61.42,168.58,61.62,168.58,61.87z M168.36,64.26v6.64h-1.32v-6.64H168.36z"></path>
<path class="st4" d="M170.6,64.26h1.25c0.04,0.45,0.06,0.81,0.06,1.09h0.04c0.17-0.36,0.45-0.67,0.85-0.91s0.84-0.36,1.3-0.36
    c0.81,0,1.43,0.25,1.85,0.76c0.42,0.5,0.63,1.15,0.63,1.95v4.12h-1.32v-3.68c0-1.35-0.5-2.03-1.51-2.03
    c-0.52,0-0.95,0.2-1.28,0.6c-0.33,0.4-0.5,0.93-0.5,1.58v3.53h-1.32v-5.21C170.65,65.12,170.63,64.64,170.6,64.26z"></path>
<path class="st4" d="M178.48,73.05l0.84-1.02c0.29,0.33,0.65,0.59,1.09,0.78c0.44,0.2,0.88,0.29,1.33,0.29
    c1.56,0,2.34-0.82,2.34-2.45V69.8h-0.03c-0.24,0.36-0.57,0.65-0.99,0.85c-0.42,0.2-0.87,0.3-1.34,0.3c-1,0-1.81-0.33-2.42-0.98
    s-0.92-1.47-0.92-2.44c0-0.98,0.31-1.8,0.92-2.46c0.62-0.66,1.42-0.99,2.41-0.99c0.49,0,0.96,0.11,1.39,0.32
    c0.43,0.21,0.77,0.52,1.01,0.92h0.03v-1.06h1.27v6.3c0,0.5-0.06,0.97-0.19,1.39c-0.13,0.42-0.33,0.81-0.6,1.17
    c-0.28,0.35-0.66,0.63-1.15,0.83c-0.49,0.2-1.07,0.3-1.73,0.3c-0.58,0-1.16-0.11-1.75-0.32
    C179.39,73.72,178.89,73.43,178.48,73.05z M179.72,67.51c0,0.64,0.2,1.19,0.6,1.65c0.4,0.46,0.93,0.69,1.6,0.69
    c0.67,0,1.22-0.22,1.63-0.67c0.42-0.44,0.62-1,0.62-1.67c0-0.64-0.21-1.19-0.64-1.65c-0.42-0.46-0.96-0.69-1.62-0.69
    c-0.67,0-1.21,0.22-1.6,0.67C179.92,66.29,179.72,66.85,179.72,67.51z"></path>
<path class="st4" d="M190.9,64.26v1.08h-1.76v3.46c0,0.4,0.07,0.69,0.22,0.86c0.15,0.17,0.39,0.26,0.71,0.26
    c0.29,0,0.55-0.06,0.77-0.17l0.04,1.08c-0.34,0.12-0.71,0.18-1.12,0.18c-0.63,0-1.1-0.17-1.44-0.52c-0.33-0.35-0.5-0.87-0.5-1.55
    v-3.6h-1.27v-1.08h1.27v-1.9h1.3v1.9H190.9z"></path>
<path class="st4" d="M197.95,65.06c0.68,0.65,1.02,1.49,1.02,2.51c0,1.02-0.34,1.86-1.03,2.52s-1.54,0.99-2.56,0.99
    c-1.02,0-1.87-0.33-2.55-0.99c-0.68-0.66-1.02-1.5-1.02-2.52c0-1.02,0.34-1.85,1.01-2.51s1.53-0.98,2.56-0.98
    C196.42,64.08,197.27,64.41,197.95,65.06z M197.01,69.27c0.4-0.47,0.59-1.04,0.59-1.7c0-0.66-0.2-1.23-0.59-1.69
    c-0.4-0.47-0.94-0.7-1.62-0.7c-0.68,0-1.22,0.23-1.62,0.7c-0.4,0.47-0.59,1.03-0.59,1.69c0,0.66,0.2,1.23,0.59,1.7
    c0.4,0.47,0.94,0.71,1.62,0.71C196.07,69.97,196.61,69.74,197.01,69.27z"></path>
<path class="st4" d="M200.74,64.26h1.25c0.04,0.45,0.06,0.81,0.06,1.09h0.04c0.17-0.36,0.45-0.67,0.85-0.91s0.84-0.36,1.3-0.36
    c0.81,0,1.43,0.25,1.85,0.76c0.42,0.5,0.63,1.15,0.63,1.95v4.12h-1.32v-3.68c0-1.35-0.5-2.03-1.51-2.03
    c-0.52,0-0.95,0.2-1.28,0.6c-0.33,0.4-0.5,0.93-0.5,1.58v3.53h-1.32v-5.21C200.79,65.12,200.77,64.64,200.74,64.26z"></path>
                                    </g>
                                                                        <g class="select_region" data-id="2">
                                        <path class="st0" d="M50.39,198.18l1.69-0.23l0.3,0.11c0.64,0.24,59.06,21.89,148.83,41.33c1.78-7.28,10.8-44.12,12-47.73
   c0.4-1.19,0.76-2.43,1.12-3.64c0.84-2.83,1.63-5.5,2.71-7.3c0.94-1.58,0.97-2.55,0.85-2.83c-0.02-0.05-0.02-0.06-0.11-0.08
   c-0.24-0.07-0.7-0.09-1.15-0.11c-1.28-0.07-2.87-0.16-3.78-1.27c-0.34-0.42-0.71-1.15-0.54-2.29c0.06-0.43,0.12-0.87,0.18-1.33
   c0.31-2.48,0.67-5.28,2.36-7.1c1.5-1.62,6.1-6.13,6.68-6.52c0.26-0.19,1.4-1.44,1.9-2.28c0.17-0.28,0.52-1.05,0.86-1.8
   c0.95-2.09,1.73-3.76,2.46-4.62c0.32-0.38,0.97-1.27,1.73-2.29c1.67-2.27,3.75-5.1,4.97-6.23c1.45-1.34,2.2-2.13,2.28-2.76
   l0.02-0.17c0.31-2.4,0.01-3.03-0.2-3.19l-0.3-0.23c-1.41-1.07-4.34-3.28-5.15-7.57c-0.07-0.38-0.13-0.8-0.19-1.24
   c-4.5-1.2-25.46-6.81-28.48-7.74c-3.29-1.01-10.64-2.59-12.1-2.59c-0.42,0-1.25,0.19-2.21,0.41c-2.13,0.49-5.36,1.23-9.19,1.09
   c-3.5-0.13-5.1-0.69-6.27-1.1c-0.71-0.25-1.14-0.4-1.8-0.4c-1.14,0-2.52,0.45-3.73,0.84c-0.9,0.29-1.68,0.55-2.35,0.62
   c-1.08,0.12-6.02-0.01-7.36-0.96c-0.43-0.3-0.71-0.65-0.97-0.96c-0.38-0.46-0.54-0.63-0.93-0.68c-0.26-0.04-0.57,0.07-1.15,0.29
   c-1,0.37-2.36,0.87-4.72,0.9c-3.02,0.03-3.93-0.52-5.26-1.52c-0.38-0.29-0.77-0.58-1.33-0.92l-0.15-0.09
   c-2.24-1.35-3.59-2.17-6.24-2.48c-2.18-0.25-2.95-0.79-3.72-1.47c-0.25-0.22-0.44-0.39-0.77-0.54c-0.43-0.2-1.7,0.39-2.51,1.02
   l-0.29,0.17c-0.11,0.05-2.81,1.17-5.67,1.17c-2.84,0-6-0.21-7.53-2.76c-0.78-1.3-3.2-2.49-3.99-2.81l-0.83-0.33l0.05-0.9
   c0-0.08,0.49-8.52,0.49-11.96c0-2.75-3.5-4.13-4.33-4.13c-2.17,0-3.51-0.99-4.22-3.1c-0.37-1.1-1.03-1.45-2.85-1.93
   c-1.31-0.35-3.7-0.1-4.51,0.03l-0.33,0.05l-0.65-0.25c-1.03,1.35-2.75,3.68-3.38,4.84c-0.91,1.7-3.07,14.28-7.04,21.13
   c-3.98,6.85-5.74,13.43-10.17,27.13c-4.43,13.7-15.39,27.52-15.39,27.52c-3.2,3.78-7.76,8.8-7.63,12.2
   c0.27,7.04-3.39,15.78-3.33,17.74C47.09,195.55,48.97,197.15,50.39,198.18z"></path>
<path class="st4" d="M130.05,161.73c0,1.52-0.5,2.77-1.49,3.75c-0.99,0.98-2.25,1.47-3.77,1.47c-1.51,0-2.76-0.49-3.75-1.47
    c-0.99-0.98-1.48-2.23-1.48-3.75c0-1.53,0.49-2.78,1.48-3.74c0.99-0.97,2.24-1.45,3.76-1.45c1.52,0,2.78,0.48,3.77,1.45
    C129.56,158.96,130.05,160.2,130.05,161.73z M128.56,161.73c0-1.12-0.35-2.06-1.04-2.83c-0.69-0.77-1.6-1.15-2.73-1.15
    c-1.11,0-2.01,0.38-2.7,1.15c-0.69,0.76-1.04,1.71-1.04,2.83c0,1.13,0.34,2.08,1.04,2.84c0.69,0.76,1.59,1.14,2.7,1.14
    c1.13,0,2.04-0.38,2.73-1.14S128.56,162.86,128.56,161.73z"></path>
<path class="st4" d="M131.87,161.5c0-0.57-0.02-1.05-0.06-1.43h1.25c0.04,0.45,0.06,0.82,0.06,1.12h0.04
    c0.19-0.39,0.46-0.71,0.83-0.94c0.36-0.24,0.77-0.36,1.2-0.36c0.21,0,0.38,0.02,0.52,0.06l-0.06,1.22
    c-0.19-0.05-0.39-0.07-0.6-0.07c-0.6,0-1.06,0.21-1.38,0.62c-0.32,0.41-0.48,0.92-0.48,1.51v3.49h-1.32V161.5z"></path>
<path class="st4" d="M142.88,163.33c0,0.2,0,0.34-0.01,0.45h-5.26c0.02,0.57,0.24,1.05,0.66,1.43s0.92,0.58,1.5,0.58
    c0.83,0,1.47-0.34,1.93-1.01l0.92,0.74c-0.7,0.91-1.65,1.36-2.86,1.36c-1.02,0-1.85-0.32-2.51-0.97
    c-0.66-0.64-0.99-1.48-0.99-2.52c0-1.03,0.33-1.87,0.98-2.53c0.65-0.66,1.47-0.99,2.45-0.99c0.98,0,1.76,0.31,2.33,0.93
    C142.59,161.44,142.88,162.28,142.88,163.33z M137.6,162.8h3.95c-0.02-0.55-0.19-1-0.5-1.35c-0.32-0.35-0.77-0.53-1.36-0.53
    c-0.56,0-1.04,0.18-1.43,0.55C137.87,161.83,137.65,162.28,137.6,162.8z"></path>
<path class="st4" d="M144.39,168.86l0.84-1.02c0.29,0.33,0.65,0.59,1.09,0.78c0.44,0.2,0.88,0.29,1.33,0.29
    c1.56,0,2.34-0.82,2.34-2.45v-0.85h-0.03c-0.24,0.36-0.57,0.65-0.99,0.85s-0.87,0.3-1.34,0.3c-1,0-1.81-0.33-2.42-0.98
    s-0.92-1.47-0.92-2.44c0-0.98,0.31-1.8,0.92-2.46s1.42-0.99,2.41-0.99c0.49,0,0.96,0.11,1.39,0.32c0.43,0.21,0.76,0.52,1.01,0.92
    h0.03v-1.06h1.27v6.3c0,0.5-0.06,0.97-0.19,1.39s-0.33,0.81-0.6,1.17s-0.66,0.63-1.15,0.83c-0.49,0.2-1.07,0.3-1.73,0.3
    c-0.58,0-1.16-0.11-1.75-0.32C145.3,169.53,144.8,169.23,144.39,168.86z M145.64,163.32c0,0.64,0.2,1.2,0.6,1.65
    c0.4,0.46,0.93,0.69,1.6,0.69c0.67,0,1.22-0.22,1.63-0.67s0.62-1,0.62-1.67c0-0.64-0.21-1.19-0.64-1.65
    c-0.42-0.46-0.96-0.69-1.62-0.69c-0.67,0-1.21,0.22-1.6,0.67C145.83,162.1,145.64,162.65,145.64,163.32z"></path>
<path class="st4" d="M159.26,160.87c0.68,0.65,1.02,1.49,1.02,2.51s-0.34,1.86-1.03,2.52c-0.69,0.66-1.54,0.99-2.56,0.99
    s-1.87-0.33-2.55-0.99c-0.68-0.66-1.02-1.5-1.02-2.52s0.34-1.85,1.01-2.51s1.53-0.98,2.55-0.98S158.58,160.21,159.26,160.87z
     M158.31,165.07c0.4-0.47,0.59-1.04,0.59-1.7s-0.2-1.23-0.59-1.69s-0.94-0.7-1.62-0.7s-1.22,0.23-1.62,0.7
    c-0.4,0.47-0.59,1.03-0.59,1.69s0.2,1.23,0.59,1.7c0.4,0.47,0.94,0.71,1.62,0.71S157.92,165.55,158.31,165.07z"></path>
<path class="st4" d="M162.04,160.07h1.25c0.04,0.45,0.06,0.81,0.06,1.09h0.04c0.17-0.36,0.45-0.67,0.85-0.91
    c0.4-0.24,0.84-0.36,1.3-0.36c0.81,0,1.43,0.25,1.85,0.76s0.63,1.15,0.63,1.95v4.12h-1.32v-3.68c0-1.35-0.5-2.03-1.51-2.03
    c-0.52,0-0.95,0.2-1.28,0.6c-0.33,0.4-0.5,0.93-0.5,1.58v3.53h-1.32v-5.21C162.1,160.93,162.08,160.45,162.04,160.07z"></path>
                                    </g>
                                                                </svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(function() {
  $('.select_region').on('click', function() {
    $('.select_region').removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function() {
  $('.select_region').on('click', function() {
    $('.select_region').removeClass("active");
    this.classList.add("active");
  });
});
```

```css
.select_region:hover .st0, .select_region.active .st0 {
    cursor: pointer;
    fill: #297AFF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pg-region__map">
  <style type="text/css">
    .st0 {
      fill: #43495E;
    }
    
    .st1 {
      fill: #297AFF;
    }
    
    .st2 {
      fill: #363647;
    }
    
    .st3 {
      opacity: 0;
      fill: #297AFF;
    }
    
    .st4 {
      fill: #FFFFFF;
    }
    
    .st5 {
      fill: #565673;
    }
    
    .st6 {
      fill: #636A84;
    }
  </style>
  <svg id="usa" viewBox="0 0 1339 812">
                                                                    <g class="select_region" data-id="1">
                                        <path class="st0" d="M91.84,80.26l3.09,1.2c0.94-0.12,3.45-0.38,5.19,0.07c1.96,0.52,3.79,1.18,4.58,3.55
   c0.4,1.2,0.87,1.4,1.85,1.4c2.04,0,6.83,2.26,6.83,6.63c0,2.89-0.32,8.98-0.44,11.24c1.21,0.58,3.37,1.8,4.37,3.47
   c0.77,1.28,2.71,1.54,5.38,1.54c2.03,0,4.03-0.72,4.56-0.92c0.74-0.55,3.07-2.1,4.97-1.21c0.66,0.31,1.06,0.66,1.37,0.93
   c0.45,0.4,0.77,0.68,2.35,0.86c3.19,0.37,4.89,1.39,7.25,2.82l0.15,0.09c0.66,0.4,1.15,0.76,1.53,1.06
   c0.98,0.74,1.4,1.04,3.72,1.01c1.94-0.03,3.02-0.42,3.89-0.75c0.76-0.28,1.48-0.55,2.37-0.42c1.37,0.2,2.05,1.02,2.5,1.56
   c0.18,0.22,0.33,0.4,0.49,0.51c0.61,0.32,4.27,0.66,5.65,0.51c0.41-0.04,1.1-0.27,1.84-0.51c1.32-0.43,2.97-0.96,4.5-0.96
   c1.09,0,1.84,0.26,2.63,0.54c1.07,0.38,2.41,0.85,5.53,0.96c3.5,0.13,6.41-0.54,8.53-1.03c1.2-0.28,2.07-0.48,2.77-0.48
   c1.87,0,9.47,1.66,12.84,2.7c2.77,0.86,21.72,5.93,27.52,7.48c-0.21-4.05,0-8.93,0.2-11.25c0.16-1.87,1.28-6.88,2.19-10.9
   c0.45-2,0.84-3.73,0.99-4.55c0.15-0.79,0.59-2.78,1.21-5.53c1.33-5.88,3.33-14.76,3.86-18.67c0.18-1.3,0.31-2.32,0.41-3.17
   c0.36-2.87,0.47-3.73,1.27-6.07c1.46-4.29,3.15-9.5,3.41-10.8c0.27-1.38,1.12-4.91,1.57-6.82l0.2-0.86
   c0.13-0.57,0.69-4.06,1.21-7.46c-15.82-3.51-25.8-5.91-27.54-6.35c-7.43-1.91-37.81-9.68-42.02-11.1
   c-4.21-1.42-24.36-6.46-24.36-6.46c-3.57-1.08-11.05-3.77-13.6-3.52s-2.64,2.15-2.49,3.03s2.25,2.35,2.84,4.06s3.08,2.1,2.89,4.45
   c-0.2,2.35-1.86,3.38-2.79,3.86c-0.93,0.49-0.15,4.26,0.05,4.65s1.61-0.1,1.52,0.88c-0.1,0.98-1.47,1.86-1.52,2.01
   s-0.1,5.28-0.1,5.28s1.42,0.49,1.86,0.93c0.44,0.44,0.29,2.74-0.05,2.93c-0.34,0.2-2.35,0.05-2.35,0.05
   c-0.44-3.13-1.22-3.03-1.76-5.09c-0.54-2.05-2.91-1.96-2.91-1.96l0.15-3.5c0,0,2.54-1.54,2.89-1.79c0.34-0.24,0.24-2.84-0.32-2.71
   s-4.24,2.63-4.7,3.02c-0.46,0.39-0.68,3.8-0.68,3.8s-4.6,0.77-5.12-0.15c-0.52-0.91-3.46-3.39-9.52-4.5
   c-10.34-1.89-19.24-13.83-20.28-13.63c-1.04,0.2-0.85,2.09-0.91,4.3c-0.07,2.22-2.8,7.96-2.87,9.52s2.15,2.48,2.15,2.48
   s0.33,8.54,0.33,11.09s-0.85,3.46-1.24,4.57c-0.39,1.11,1.11,1.83,1.24,2.67c0.13,0.85,0.59,4.63,0.65,6.39
   c0.07,1.76,4.17,2.74,4.17,2.74v2.09c0,0-5.02-0.26-5.35,0c-0.33,0.26-1.04,5.35-0.91,5.74c0.13,0.39,4.3,0.85,4.3,1.24
   c0,0.39-2.15,5.87-2.35,6c-0.2,0.13-3.72-0.59-4.04-0.46c-0.33,0.13-0.78,3.65-0.65,4.37C90.85,79.26,91.28,79.73,91.84,80.26z"></path>
<path class="st4" d="M132.22,60.98l2.18,7.9h0.03l2.32-7.9h1.53l2.31,7.9h0.03l2.18-7.9h1.47l-2.91,9.91h-1.44l-2.41-7.97h-0.03
    l-2.41,7.97h-1.44l-2.91-9.91H132.22z"></path>
<path class="st4" d="M149.18,66.78V66.6c0-0.48-0.15-0.84-0.44-1.08c-0.29-0.25-0.69-0.37-1.2-0.37c-0.75,0-1.38,0.26-1.89,0.77
    l-0.7-0.84c0.69-0.66,1.6-0.99,2.72-0.99c0.91,0,1.61,0.24,2.07,0.72c0.47,0.48,0.7,1.11,0.7,1.88v2.9c0,0.58,0.03,1.02,0.1,1.32
    h-1.19c-0.07-0.32-0.11-0.63-0.11-0.95h-0.04c-0.49,0.75-1.24,1.12-2.23,1.12c-0.28,0-0.56-0.04-0.83-0.11
    c-0.27-0.07-0.53-0.19-0.77-0.34s-0.44-0.36-0.59-0.64c-0.15-0.28-0.22-0.6-0.22-0.96c0-0.38,0.09-0.72,0.27-1
    s0.41-0.5,0.69-0.66c0.28-0.15,0.64-0.27,1.07-0.36s0.84-0.15,1.23-0.18C148.21,66.79,148.66,66.78,149.18,66.78z M149.18,67.73
    h-0.32c-1.97,0-2.95,0.42-2.95,1.26c0,0.36,0.13,0.63,0.39,0.79c0.26,0.16,0.58,0.24,0.97,0.24c0.6,0,1.07-0.18,1.41-0.54
    c0.34-0.36,0.51-0.83,0.51-1.41V67.73z"></path>
<path class="st4" d="M157.13,65.17l-0.91,0.77c-0.15-0.24-0.36-0.44-0.64-0.59c-0.28-0.15-0.58-0.23-0.9-0.23
    c-0.34,0-0.63,0.07-0.87,0.22s-0.36,0.36-0.36,0.65c0,0.26,0.12,0.46,0.35,0.6s0.62,0.27,1.16,0.39
    c1.48,0.33,2.23,0.98,2.23,1.96c0,0.73-0.25,1.27-0.76,1.62c-0.51,0.35-1.14,0.52-1.88,0.52c-0.52,0-1.02-0.1-1.5-0.31
    s-0.87-0.5-1.18-0.88l0.94-0.8c0.18,0.27,0.43,0.49,0.75,0.67c0.32,0.17,0.66,0.26,1.02,0.26c0.37,0,0.69-0.08,0.94-0.23
    c0.25-0.15,0.38-0.4,0.38-0.74c0-0.29-0.13-0.51-0.4-0.66s-0.71-0.3-1.34-0.45c-0.26-0.06-0.49-0.14-0.69-0.21
    s-0.4-0.18-0.6-0.31s-0.36-0.31-0.48-0.53c-0.11-0.22-0.17-0.48-0.17-0.78c0-0.67,0.25-1.18,0.74-1.52
    c0.49-0.34,1.08-0.51,1.77-0.51c0.48,0,0.95,0.1,1.39,0.29S156.9,64.83,157.13,65.17z"></path>
<path class="st4" d="M160.19,65.27h0.03c0.16-0.34,0.43-0.62,0.82-0.85c0.39-0.23,0.81-0.34,1.28-0.34
    c0.81,0,1.43,0.25,1.85,0.76s0.63,1.15,0.63,1.95v4.12h-1.32v-3.67c0-1.35-0.5-2.03-1.5-2.03c-0.52,0-0.95,0.2-1.29,0.6
    c-0.34,0.4-0.5,0.93-0.5,1.58v3.51h-1.32V60.31h1.32V65.27z"></path>
<path class="st4" d="M168.58,61.87c0,0.23-0.09,0.43-0.26,0.59c-0.17,0.16-0.38,0.25-0.62,0.25c-0.24,0-0.45-0.08-0.62-0.25
    c-0.17-0.16-0.25-0.36-0.25-0.59s0.08-0.43,0.25-0.6s0.37-0.25,0.62-0.25c0.24,0,0.45,0.08,0.62,0.24
    C168.49,61.42,168.58,61.62,168.58,61.87z M168.36,64.26v6.64h-1.32v-6.64H168.36z"></path>
<path class="st4" d="M170.6,64.26h1.25c0.04,0.45,0.06,0.81,0.06,1.09h0.04c0.17-0.36,0.45-0.67,0.85-0.91s0.84-0.36,1.3-0.36
    c0.81,0,1.43,0.25,1.85,0.76c0.42,0.5,0.63,1.15,0.63,1.95v4.12h-1.32v-3.68c0-1.35-0.5-2.03-1.51-2.03
    c-0.52,0-0.95,0.2-1.28,0.6c-0.33,0.4-0.5,0.93-0.5,1.58v3.53h-1.32v-5.21C170.65,65.12,170.63,64.64,170.6,64.26z"></path>
<path class="st4" d="M178.48,73.05l0.84-1.02c0.29,0.33,0.65,0.59,1.09,0.78c0.44,0.2,0.88,0.29,1.33,0.29
    c1.56,0,2.34-0.82,2.34-2.45V69.8h-0.03c-0.24,0.36-0.57,0.65-0.99,0.85c-0.42,0.2-0.87,0.3-1.34,0.3c-1,0-1.81-0.33-2.42-0.98
    s-0.92-1.47-0.92-2.44c0-0.98,0.31-1.8,0.92-2.46c0.62-0.66,1.42-0.99,2.41-0.99c0.49,0,0.96,0.11,1.39,0.32
    c0.43,0.21,0.77,0.52,1.01,0.92h0.03v-1.06h1.27v6.3c0,0.5-0.06,0.97-0.19,1.39c-0.13,0.42-0.33,0.81-0.6,1.17
    c-0.28,0.35-0.66,0.63-1.15,0.83c-0.49,0.2-1.07,0.3-1.73,0.3c-0.58,0-1.16-0.11-1.75-0.32
    C179.39,73.72,178.89,73.43,178.48,73.05z M179.72,67.51c0,0.64,0.2,1.19,0.6,1.65c0.4,0.46,0.93,0.69,1.6,0.69
    c0.67,0,1.22-0.22,1.63-0.67c0.42-0.44,0.62-1,0.62-1.67c0-0.64-0.21-1.19-0.64-1.65c-0.42-0.46-0.96-0.69-1.62-0.69
    c-0.67,0-1.21,0.22-1.6,0.67C179.92,66.29,179.72,66.85,179.72,67.51z"></path>
<path class="st4" d="M190.9,64.26v1.08h-1.76v3.46c0,0.4,0.07,0.69,0.22,0.86c0.15,0.17,0.39,0.26,0.71,0.26
    c0.29,0,0.55-0.06,0.77-0.17l0.04,1.08c-0.34,0.12-0.71,0.18-1.12,0.18c-0.63,0-1.1-0.17-1.44-0.52c-0.33-0.35-0.5-0.87-0.5-1.55
    v-3.6h-1.27v-1.08h1.27v-1.9h1.3v1.9H190.9z"></path>
<path class="st4" d="M197.95,65.06c0.68,0.65,1.02,1.49,1.02,2.51c0,1.02-0.34,1.86-1.03,2.52s-1.54,0.99-2.56,0.99
    c-1.02,0-1.87-0.33-2.55-0.99c-0.68-0.66-1.02-1.5-1.02-2.52c0-1.02,0.34-1.85,1.01-2.51s1.53-0.98,2.56-0.98
    C196.42,64.08,197.27,64.41,197.95,65.06z M197.01,69.27c0.4-0.47,0.59-1.04,0.59-1.7c0-0.66-0.2-1.23-0.59-1.69
    c-0.4-0.47-0.94-0.7-1.62-0.7c-0.68,0-1.22,0.23-1.62,0.7c-0.4,0.47-0.59,1.03-0.59,1.69c0,0.66,0.2,1.23,0.59,1.7
    c0.4,0.47,0.94,0.71,1.62,0.71C196.07,69.97,196.61,69.74,197.01,69.27z"></path>
<path class="st4" d="M200.74,64.26h1.25c0.04,0.45,0.06,0.81,0.06,1.09h0.04c0.17-0.36,0.45-0.67,0.85-0.91s0.84-0.36,1.3-0.36
    c0.81,0,1.43,0.25,1.85,0.76c0.42,0.5,0.63,1.15,0.63,1.95v4.12h-1.32v-3.68c0-1.35-0.5-2.03-1.51-2.03
    c-0.52,0-0.95,0.2-1.28,0.6c-0.33,0.4-0.5,0.93-0.5,1.58v3.53h-1.32v-5.21C200.79,65.12,200.77,64.64,200.74,64.26z"></path>
                                    </g>
                                                                        <g class="select_region" data-id="2">
                                        <path class="st0" d="M50.39,198.18l1.69-0.23l0.3,0.11c0.64,0.24,59.06,21.89,148.83,41.33c1.78-7.28,10.8-44.12,12-47.73
   c0.4-1.19,0.76-2.43,1.12-3.64c0.84-2.83,1.63-5.5,2.71-7.3c0.94-1.58,0.97-2.55,0.85-2.83c-0.02-0.05-0.02-0.06-0.11-0.08
   c-0.24-0.07-0.7-0.09-1.15-0.11c-1.28-0.07-2.87-0.16-3.78-1.27c-0.34-0.42-0.71-1.15-0.54-2.29c0.06-0.43,0.12-0.87,0.18-1.33
   c0.31-2.48,0.67-5.28,2.36-7.1c1.5-1.62,6.1-6.13,6.68-6.52c0.26-0.19,1.4-1.44,1.9-2.28c0.17-0.28,0.52-1.05,0.86-1.8
   c0.95-2.09,1.73-3.76,2.46-4.62c0.32-0.38,0.97-1.27,1.73-2.29c1.67-2.27,3.75-5.1,4.97-6.23c1.45-1.34,2.2-2.13,2.28-2.76
   l0.02-0.17c0.31-2.4,0.01-3.03-0.2-3.19l-0.3-0.23c-1.41-1.07-4.34-3.28-5.15-7.57c-0.07-0.38-0.13-0.8-0.19-1.24
   c-4.5-1.2-25.46-6.81-28.48-7.74c-3.29-1.01-10.64-2.59-12.1-2.59c-0.42,0-1.25,0.19-2.21,0.41c-2.13,0.49-5.36,1.23-9.19,1.09
   c-3.5-0.13-5.1-0.69-6.27-1.1c-0.71-0.25-1.14-0.4-1.8-0.4c-1.14,0-2.52,0.45-3.73,0.84c-0.9,0.29-1.68,0.55-2.35,0.62
   c-1.08,0.12-6.02-0.01-7.36-0.96c-0.43-0.3-0.71-0.65-0.97-0.96c-0.38-0.46-0.54-0.63-0.93-0.68c-0.26-0.04-0.57,0.07-1.15,0.29
   c-1,0.37-2.36,0.87-4.72,0.9c-3.02,0.03-3.93-0.52-5.26-1.52c-0.38-0.29-0.77-0.58-1.33-0.92l-0.15-0.09
   c-2.24-1.35-3.59-2.17-6.24-2.48c-2.18-0.25-2.95-0.79-3.72-1.47c-0.25-0.22-0.44-0.39-0.77-0.54c-0.43-0.2-1.7,0.39-2.51,1.02
   l-0.29,0.17c-0.11,0.05-2.81,1.17-5.67,1.17c-2.84,0-6-0.21-7.53-2.76c-0.78-1.3-3.2-2.49-3.99-2.81l-0.83-0.33l0.05-0.9
   c0-0.08,0.49-8.52,0.49-11.96c0-2.75-3.5-4.13-4.33-4.13c-2.17,0-3.51-0.99-4.22-3.1c-0.37-1.1-1.03-1.45-2.85-1.93
   c-1.31-0.35-3.7-0.1-4.51,0.03l-0.33,0.05l-0.65-0.25c-1.03,1.35-2.75,3.68-3.38,4.84c-0.91,1.7-3.07,14.28-7.04,21.13
   c-3.98,6.85-5.74,13.43-10.17,27.13c-4.43,13.7-15.39,27.52-15.39,27.52c-3.2,3.78-7.76,8.8-7.63,12.2
   c0.27,7.04-3.39,15.78-3.33,17.74C47.09,195.55,48.97,197.15,50.39,198.18z"></path>
<path class="st4" d="M130.05,161.73c0,1.52-0.5,2.77-1.49,3.75c-0.99,0.98-2.25,1.47-3.77,1.47c-1.51,0-2.76-0.49-3.75-1.47
    c-0.99-0.98-1.48-2.23-1.48-3.75c0-1.53,0.49-2.78,1.48-3.74c0.99-0.97,2.24-1.45,3.76-1.45c1.52,0,2.78,0.48,3.77,1.45
    C129.56,158.96,130.05,160.2,130.05,161.73z M128.56,161.73c0-1.12-0.35-2.06-1.04-2.83c-0.69-0.77-1.6-1.15-2.73-1.15
    c-1.11,0-2.01,0.38-2.7,1.15c-0.69,0.76-1.04,1.71-1.04,2.83c0,1.13,0.34,2.08,1.04,2.84c0.69,0.76,1.59,1.14,2.7,1.14
    c1.13,0,2.04-0.38,2.73-1.14S128.56,162.86,128.56,161.73z"></path>
<path class="st4" d="M131.87,161.5c0-0.57-0.02-1.05-0.06-1.43h1.25c0.04,0.45,0.06,0.82,0.06,1.12h0.04
    c0.19-0.39,0.46-0.71,0.83-0.94c0.36-0.24,0.77-0.36,1.2-0.36c0.21,0,0.38,0.02,0.52,0.06l-0.06,1.22
    c-0.19-0.05-0.39-0.07-0.6-0.07c-0.6,0-1.06,0.21-1.38,0.62c-0.32,0.41-0.48,0.92-0.48,1.51v3.49h-1.32V161.5z"></path>
<path class="st4" d="M142.88,163.33c0,0.2,0,0.34-0.01,0.45h-5.26c0.02,0.57,0.24,1.05,0.66,1.43s0.92,0.58,1.5,0.58
    c0.83,0,1.47-0.34,1.93-1.01l0.92,0.74c-0.7,0.91-1.65,1.36-2.86,1.36c-1.02,0-1.85-0.32-2.51-0.97
    c-0.66-0.64-0.99-1.48-0.99-2.52c0-1.03,0.33-1.87,0.98-2.53c0.65-0.66,1.47-0.99,2.45-0.99c0.98,0,1.76,0.31,2.33,0.93
    C142.59,161.44,142.88,162.28,142.88,163.33z M137.6,162.8h3.95c-0.02-0.55-0.19-1-0.5-1.35c-0.32-0.35-0.77-0.53-1.36-0.53
    c-0.56,0-1.04,0.18-1.43,0.55C137.87,161.83,137.65,162.28,137.6,162.8z"></path>
<path class="st4" d="M144.39,168.86l0.84-1.02c0.29,0.33,0.65,0.59,1.09,0.78c0.44,0.2,0.88,0.29,1.33,0.29
    c1.56,0,2.34-0.82,2.34-2.45v-0.85h-0.03c-0.24,0.36-0.57,0.65-0.99,0.85s-0.87,0.3-1.34,0.3c-1,0-1.81-0.33-2.42-0.98
    s-0.92-1.47-0.92-2.44c0-0.98,0.31-1.8,0.92-2.46s1.42-0.99,2.41-0.99c0.49,0,0.96,0.11,1.39,0.32c0.43,0.21,0.76,0.52,1.01,0.92
    h0.03v-1.06h1.27v6.3c0,0.5-0.06,0.97-0.19,1.39s-0.33,0.81-0.6,1.17s-0.66,0.63-1.15,0.83c-0.49,0.2-1.07,0.3-1.73,0.3
    c-0.58,0-1.16-0.11-1.75-0.32C145.3,169.53,144.8,169.23,144.39,168.86z M145.64,163.32c0,0.64,0.2,1.2,0.6,1.65
    c0.4,0.46,0.93,0.69,1.6,0.69c0.67,0,1.22-0.22,1.63-0.67s0.62-1,0.62-1.67c0-0.64-0.21-1.19-0.64-1.65
    c-0.42-0.46-0.96-0.69-1.62-0.69c-0.67,0-1.21,0.22-1.6,0.67C145.83,162.1,145.64,162.65,145.64,163.32z"></path>
<path class="st4" d="M159.26,160.87c0.68,0.65,1.02,1.49,1.02,2.51s-0.34,1.86-1.03,2.52c-0.69,0.66-1.54,0.99-2.56,0.99
    s-1.87-0.33-2.55-0.99c-0.68-0.66-1.02-1.5-1.02-2.52s0.34-1.85,1.01-2.51s1.53-0.98,2.55-0.98S158.58,160.21,159.26,160.87z
     M158.31,165.07c0.4-0.47,0.59-1.04,0.59-1.7s-0.2-1.23-0.59-1.69s-0.94-0.7-1.62-0.7s-1.22,0.23-1.62,0.7
    c-0.4,0.47-0.59,1.03-0.59,1.69s0.2,1.23,0.59,1.7c0.4,0.47,0.94,0.71,1.62,0.71S157.92,165.55,158.31,165.07z"></path>
<path class="st4" d="M162.04,160.07h1.25c0.04,0.45,0.06,0.81,0.06,1.09h0.04c0.17-0.36,0.45-0.67,0.85-0.91
    c0.4-0.24,0.84-0.36,1.3-0.36c0.81,0,1.43,0.25,1.85,0.76s0.63,1.15,0.63,1.95v4.12h-1.32v-3.68c0-1.35-0.5-2.03-1.51-2.03
    c-0.52,0-0.95,0.2-1.28,0.6c-0.33,0.4-0.5,0.93-0.5,1.58v3.53h-1.32v-5.21C162.1,160.93,162.08,160.45,162.04,160.07z"></path>
                                    </g>
                                                                </svg>
</div>
```